# Partial table in latex

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make this in Latex. Is it possible to do it with table/tabular environment? (All cells are supposed to be equal in size)

[image]

Comment: Do the cell contents have to be left-aligned? Or should they maybe be centered?

Comment: @Mico Does not matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether the cell contents should be centered or left-aligned. The following solution assumes that they should be left-aligned.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type

\begin{document}

\sffamily % optional
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % optional (for a more open "look")
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{wl{7mm}|}} % use 'wc' rather than 'wl' if centering is desired
\cline{1-1}
0.1 \\
\hline
0.2 & 0.4 & 0.5\\
\hline
0.3 \\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[corners,hvlines,columns-width=6mm]{ccc}
0.1 \\
0.2 & 0.4 & 0.5 \\
0.3 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]